# How to understand the following method, and why you want to do it? org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils#adaptArgumentsIfNecessary

Tags: spring

How to understand the following method, and why we want to do it?

org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils#adaptArgumentsIfNecessary

Can someone explain me ?